# Transformar código de HTML a Script JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, html-tabla

Tengo un código hecho en HTML, CSS y JS, que en principio se sube a WordPress.
Es un pequeño sistema de selección con tablas para que muestre el modelo, año y motor del coche.
Selecciono un modelo, me muestra el año de ese modelo, selecciono un año y me muestra el motor y un enlace.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Código en HTML</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron&family=Oxanium&display=swap");

      .custom-table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        background-color: #2c3e50;
        color: #ecf0f1;
        border-radius: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }

      .custom-table th {
        padding: 15px;
        text-align: left;
      }
      .custom-table td {
        padding: 5px 15px;
        text-align: left;
      }

      .custom-table td .custom-div:hover {
        color: #11c8e0;
      }

      .custom-table th {
        background-color: #006977;
        font-family: "Orbitron", sans-serif;
        letter-spacing: 0.15em;
      }

      .custom-table tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #262626;
      }

      .custom-table tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #262626;
      }

      .custom-table td .custom-div {
        font-family: "Oxanium", sans-serif;
        color: #ecf0f1;
        padding: 5px;
        border-radius: 0px;
        background-color: transparent;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .custom-anios,
      .custom-div {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .compressed-text {
        font-family: "Oxanium", sans-serif;
        color: #ecf0f1;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px 10px;
      }

      .enlace_Potencia {
        text-transform: capitalize;
        text-decoration: none;
        line-height: auto;
        color: #ecf0f1;
        padding: 5px 25px;
      }
      .enlace_Potencia:hover {
        color: #11c8e0;
      }

      /* Estilos específicos para dispositivos de escritorio */
      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .custom-table {
          width: 30%;
          float: left;
          margin-right: 20px;
        }

        .custom-table:contains("Años") {
          width: 40%;
        }

        .custom-table:contains("Marcas") {
          width: 100% !important;
          float: none !important;
          margin-right: 0 !important;
        }
      }

      /* Estilos específicos para dispositivos móviles */
      @media (max-width: 768px) {
        .custom-table {
          width: 100% !important;
          float: none !important;
          margin-right: 0 !important;
        }

        .custom-table:contains("Marcas") {
          width: 100% !important;
          float: none !important;
          margin-right: 0 !important;
        }
      }
    </style>

    <!-- ////////////////MODELOS/////////////// -->
    <div class="compressed-text"></div>
    <table class="custom-table custom-marcas">
      <tr>
        <th><div class="custom-div">Ariel Motors</div></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="custom-div marca-modelo" data-modelo="Atom 4">Atom 4</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="custom-div marca-modelo" data-modelo="NOMAD">NOMAD</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <!-- ////////////////MODELO Y AÑOS/////////////// -->
    <!--Modelo Atom 4-->
    <table class="custom-table custom-marcas modelo-tabla" data-modelo="Atom 4">
      <tr>
        <th><div class="custom-div">Modelo Atom 4</div></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="custom-div">2018 - ...</div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!--Modelo NOMAD-->
    <table class="custom-table custom-marcas modelo-tabla" data-modelo="NOMAD">
      <tr>
        <th><div class="custom-div">Modelo NOMAD</div></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div class="custom-div">2015 - ...</div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <!-- ////////////////MOTORES/////////////// -->

    <!--Atom 4 - 2018 - ... -->
    <table
      class="custom-table custom-marcas modelo-anios-tabla"
      data-modelo="2018 - ..."
    >
      <tr>
        <th><div class="custom-div">2018 - ...</div></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th><div class="custom-div">Gasolina</div></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="custom-anios">
          <div class="custom-div">2.0T (320cv)</div>
          <div class="custom-div">
            <a class="enlace_Potencia" href="enlace_16"> revisar</a>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!--NOMAD - 2015 - ... -->
    <table
      class="custom-table custom-marcas modelo-anios-tabla"
      data-modelo="2015 - ..."
    >
      <tr>
        <th><div class="custom-div">2015 - ...</div></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th><div class="custom-div">Gasolina</div></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="custom-anios">
          <div class="custom-div">2.4 16v I-Vtec K24 (honda) (235cv)</div>
          <div class="custom-div">
            <a class="enlace_Potencia" href="enlace_17"> revisar</a>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <!-- TEXTO PARA DIFERENCIAR AÑOS SI SON IGUALES "&lrm;" "&#10240;" "&#x200B;" "&#x180E;" "&zwnj;" "&#8205;" "ㅤ"-->
    <!-- SCRIPT -->
    <script>
      // Espera a que el documento esté completamente cargado
      $(document).ready(function () {
        // Ocultar todas las tablas de modelos y años, excepto la tabla de marcas
        $(".modelo-tabla, .modelo-anios-tabla").hide();

        // Mostrar el texto indicador al cargar la página
        $(".compressed-text").text("Haz clic para desplegar las opciones");

        // Mostrar/ocultar la tabla de marcas al hacer clic en el encabezado
        $("table.custom-marcas th div").on("click", function () {
          // Alternar la visibilidad de las filas de marcas
          var marcaTable = $(this).closest("table.custom-marcas");
          marcaTable.find("tr:gt(0)").toggle();

          // Obtener el texto indicador
          var compressedText = $(".compressed-text");

          // Comprobar si la tabla de marcas está visible
          var isTableVisible = marcaTable.find("tr:gt(0):visible").length > 0;

          // Cambiar el texto según la visibilidad de las filas
          if (isTableVisible) {
            compressedText.text("Haz clic para ocultar las opciones");
          } else {
            compressedText.text("Haz clic para desplegar las opciones");
          }
        });

        // Mostrar la tabla de modelos correspondiente al hacer clic en la marca
        $("table.custom-marcas td div.marca-modelo").on("click", function () {
          // Ocultar todas las tablas de modelos y años
          $(".modelo-tabla, .modelo-anios-tabla").hide();

          // Ocultar la tabla de marcas, dejando solo el encabezado visible
          $(".custom-marcas").find("tr:gt(0)").hide();

          // Obtener el modelo seleccionado
          var modelo = $(this).data("modelo");

          // Mostrar la tabla de modelos correspondiente
          var tablaModelos = $('.modelo-tabla[data-modelo="' + modelo + '"]');
          tablaModelos.show();

          // Desplegar la tabla de modelos (si estaba comprimida)
          tablaModelos.find("tr:gt(0)").show();

          // Restaurar la visibilidad de la tabla de modelos al hacer clic en el encabezado
          tablaModelos.find("th div").on("click", function () {
            // Alternar la visibilidad de las filas de modelos
            tablaModelos.find("tr:gt(0)").toggle();
          });

          // Actualizar el texto indicador para reflejar que las opciones están desplegadas
          $(".compressed-text").text("Haz clic para desplegar las opciones");
        });

        // Mostrar la tabla de años correspondiente al hacer clic en el modelo
        $("table.modelo-tabla td div").on("click", function () {
          // Obtener el modelo seleccionado
          var modelo = $(this).text().trim();

          // Ocultar todas las tablas de años
          $(".modelo-anios-tabla").hide();

          // Mostrar la tabla de años correspondiente
          var tablaAños = $(
            '.modelo-anios-tabla[data-modelo="' + modelo + '"]'
          );
          tablaAños.show();

          // Desplegar la tabla de años (si estaba comprimida)
          tablaAños.find("tr:gt(0)").show();

          // Mostrar la tabla de motores correspondiente al seleccionar el año
          $("table.modelo-anios-tabla td div").on("click", function () {
            // Obtener el año seleccionado
            var anio = $(this).text().trim();

            // Ocultar todas las tablas de motores
            $(".modelo-anios-tabla").find("table").hide();

            // Mostrar la tabla de motores correspondiente
            var tablaMotores = $(
              '.modelo-anios-tabla[data-modelo="' +
                modelo +
                '"][data-anio="' +
                anio +
                '"]'
            );
            tablaMotores.show();

            // Desplegar la tabla de motores (si estaba comprimida)
            tablaMotores.find("tr:gt(0)").show();
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

He logrado parte del código transformarlo a script, esto debido porque hay marcas con variedad de modelos y si se carga al WordPress, la pagina colapsa.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JQuery</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>

    <style>
      @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Orbitron&family=Oxanium&display=swap");

      .custom-table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        background-color: #2c3e50;
        color: #ecf0f1;
        border-radius: 50px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }

      .custom-table th {
        padding: 15px;
        text-align: left;
      }
      .custom-table td {
        padding: 5px 15px;
        text-align: left;
      }

      .custom-table td .custom-div:hover {
        color: #11c8e0;
      }

      .custom-table th {
        background-color: #006977;
        font-family: "Orbitron", sans-serif;
        letter-spacing: 0.15em;
      }

      .custom-table tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #262626;
      }

      .custom-table tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #262626;
      }

      .custom-table td .custom-div {
        font-family: "Oxanium", sans-serif;
        color: #ecf0f1;
        padding: 5px;
        border-radius: 0px;
        background-color: transparent;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .custom-anios,
      .custom-div {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .compressed-text {
        font-family: "Oxanium", sans-serif;
        color: #ecf0f1;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 20px 10px;
      }

      .enlace_Potencia {
        text-transform: capitalize;
        text-decoration: none;
        line-height: auto;
        color: #ecf0f1;
        padding: 5px 25px;
      }
      .enlace_Potencia:hover {
        color: #11c8e0;
      }

      /* Estilos específicos para dispositivos de escritorio */
      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .custom-table {
          width: 30%;
          float: left;
          margin-right: 20px;
        }

        .custom-table:contains("Años") {
          width: 40%;
        }

        .custom-table:contains("Marcas") {
          width: 100% !important;
          float: none !important;
          margin-right: 0 !important;
        }
      }

      /* Estilos específicos para dispositivos móviles */
      @media (max-width: 768px) {
        .custom-table {
          width: 100% !important;
          float: none !important;
          margin-right: 0 !important;
        }

        .custom-table:contains("Marcas") {
          width: 100% !important;
          float: none !important;
          margin-right: 0 !important;
        }
      }
    </style>

    <div class="compressed-text"></div>
    <!-- Elimina las líneas relacionadas con las tablas individuales -->
    <div id="marca-table-container"></div>
    <div id="marca-table-container-Anios"></div>
    <div id="marca-table-container-Motor"></div>

    <script>
      var datos = {
        "Ariel Motors": {
          "Atom 4": {
            "2018 - ...": {
              Gasolina: {
                "2.0T (320cv)": "enlace_16",
              },
            },
          },
          NOMAD: {
            "2015 - ...": {
              Gasolina: {
                "2.4 16v I-Vtec K24 (honda) (235cv)": "enlace_17",
              },
            },
          },
        },
        // Puedes agregar más datos según sea necesario
      };

      function generarTablaMarca(tipo, datos) {
        var tableHTML = '<table class="custom-table">';
        $.each(datos, function (marca, modelos) {
          tableHTML += "<tr>";
          tableHTML +=
            '<th><div class="custom-div" data-' +
            tipo +
            '="' +
            marca +
            '">' +
            marca +
            "</div></th>";
          tableHTML += "</tr>";
          $.each(modelos, function (modelo) {
            tableHTML += "<tr>";
            tableHTML +=
              '<td><div class="custom-div" data-' +
              tipo +
              '="' +
              modelo +
              '">' +
              modelo +
              "</div></td>";
            tableHTML += "</tr>";
          });
        });
        tableHTML += "</table>";
        return tableHTML;
      }

      function generarTablaAnios(tipo, datos) {
        var tableHTML = "";
        $.each(datos, function (modelo, anios) {
          tableHTML +=
            '<table class="custom-table custom-marcas ' + modelo + '">';
          tableHTML += "<tr>";
          tableHTML += '<th><div class="custom-div">' + modelo + "</div></th>";
          tableHTML += "</tr>";
          $.each(anios, function (anio) {
            tableHTML += "<tr>";
            tableHTML += '<td><div class="custom-div">' + anio + "</div></td>";
            tableHTML += "</tr>";
          });
          tableHTML += "</table>";
        });
        return tableHTML;
      }

      function generarTablaMotor(tipo, datos) {
        var tableHTML = "";
        $.each(datos, function (modelo, anios) {
          $.each(anios, function (anio, motores) {
            tableHTML +=
              '<table class="custom-table custom-marcas ' +
              modelo +
              " " +
              anio +
              '">';
            tableHTML += "<tr>";
            tableHTML +=
              '<th colspan="2"><div class="custom-div">' + anio + "</div></th>";
            tableHTML += "</tr>";
            $.each(motores, function (combustible) {
              tableHTML += "<tr>";
              tableHTML +=
                '<th><div class="custom-div">' + combustible + "</div></th>";
              tableHTML += "</tr>";
              $.each(
                motores[combustible],
                function (potenciaKey, potenciaValue) {
                  tableHTML += "<tr>";
                  tableHTML += '<td class="custom-anios">';
                  tableHTML +=
                    '<div class="custom-div">' + potenciaKey + "</div>";
                  tableHTML +=
                    '<div class="custom-div"><a class="enlace_Potencia" href="' +
                    potenciaValue +
                    '">revisar</a></div>';
                  tableHTML += "</td>";
                  tableHTML += "</tr>";
                }
              );
            });
            tableHTML += "</table>";
          });
        });
        return tableHTML;
      }

      function ocultarMostrarTabla(selector, textoIndicador) {
        $(selector + " th div").on("click", function () {
          // Alternar la visibilidad de las filas
          var currentTable = $(selector);
          currentTable.find("tr:gt(0)").toggle();

          // Comprobar si la tabla está visible
          var isTableVisible = currentTable.find("tr:gt(0):visible").length > 0;

          // Cambiar el texto según la visibilidad de las filas
          if (isTableVisible) {
            $(textoIndicador).text("Haz clic para ocultar las opciones");
          } else {
            $(textoIndicador).text("Haz clic para desplegar las opciones");
          }
        });

        // Mostrar el texto indicador al cargar la página si la tabla está inicialmente oculta
        if (!$(selector).find("tr:gt(0):visible").length) {
          $(textoIndicador).text("Haz clic para desplegar las opciones");
        }
      }

      // Generar tabla inicial de marcas
      var marcasHTML = generarTablaMarca("marcas", datos);
      $("#marca-table-container").html(marcasHTML);
      ocultarMostrarTabla("#marca-table-container", ".compressed-text");

      // Lógica de clic en las celdas de marcas
      $(document).on("click", ".custom-div[data-marcas]", function () {
        var marca = $(this).data("marcas");
        var modelos = datos[marca];

        // Limpiar la tabla de años y motores
        $("#marca-table-container-Anios, #marca-table-container-Motor").html(
          ""
        );

        // Crear tabla de modelos y ocultar/mostrar
        var modelosTable = generarTablaAnios("anios", { [marca]: modelos });
        $("#marca-table-container-Anios").html(modelosTable);

        ocultarMostrarTabla("#marca-table-container-Anios", ".compressed-text");
      });

      // Lógica de clic en las celdas de modelos
      $(document).on(
        "click",
        "#marca-table-container-Anios td div",
        function () {
          var modelo = $(this).text().trim();
          var marca = $(this).closest("[data-marcas]").data("marcas");
          var anio = datos[modelo][anios];

          // Limpiar la tabla de motores
          $("#marca-table-container-Motor").empty();

          // Limpiar la tabla de años y ocultar/mostrar
          $("#marca-table-container-Anios").empty();
          var aniosTable = generarTablaAnios(
            "anios",
            { [anios]: anio },
            { [modelo]: anio }
          );
          $("#marca-table-container-Anios").append(aniosTable);
          ocultarMostrarTabla(
            "#marca-table-container-Años",
            ".compressed-text-Anios"
          );
        }
      );

      // Lógica de clic en las celdas de años
      $(document).on(
        "click",
        "#marca-table-container-Anios td div",
        function () {
          var anio = $(this).text().trim();
          var modelo = $(this).closest("[data-modelos]").data("modelos");
          var marca = $(this).closest("[data-marcas]").data("marcas");
          var motores = datos[marca][modelo][anio];

          // Generar tabla de motor
          var motorHTML = generarTablaMotor("motor", motores);
          $("#marca-table-container-Motor").html(motorHTML);
          ocultarMostrarTabla(
            "#marca-table-container-Motor",
            ".compressed-text-Motor"
          );
        }
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Aquí lo que hice fue crear los datos como arrays, implementar funciones para crear las tablas y posteriormente implementar la lógica de selección, lamentablemente no me ha funcionado.

Si alguien me puede guiar o proponer un método diferente les estaré muy agradecido.
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías describir (en la pregunta) a qué te referís con "colapsar"? Por cierto, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: la consola te dice que $ no es una funcion? si es asi cambialo por jQuery, en vez de $(); seria algo como jQuery();